# limit of expression with first and second derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits

I got the expression: $$\frac{X'(t) X''[t]+Z'(t) Z''(t)}{\sqrt{X'(t)^2+Z'(t)^2}}$$
How do I find the limit when I get to a point with $X'(t)=Z'(t)=0$, it's like everytime it happens, the limit is $\pm\sqrt{X^{\prime\prime }(t)^2+Z^{\prime\prime }(t)^2}$ is this explainable?

Comment: What are $X$ and $Z$ given by? It looks like you're differentiating the "speed" of a planar trajectory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest the following. First, let $t_0$ be a value such that $X'(t_0)=Z'(t_0)=0$. Evaluate the following limit :

$$\begin{eqnarray} L^2 &=& \lim_{t\to t_0} \left(\frac{X'(t)\, X''(t) + Z'(t)\, Z''(t)}{\sqrt{X'(t)^2 + Z'(t)^2}} \right)^2 \\ &=& \lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{\left(X'(t)\, X''(t) + Z'(t)\, Z''(t)\right)^2}{X'(t)^2 + Z'(t)^2}\end{eqnarray}$$

Apply l'Hospital rule to get :

$$\begin{eqnarray} L^2 &=& \lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{2\, \left(X'(t)\, X''(t) + Z'(t)\, Z''(t)\right)\left(X''(t)^2 + X'(t)\, X'''(t) + Z''(t)^2 + Z'(t)\, Z'''(t)\right)}{2 X'(t)\, X''(t) + 2 Z'(t)\, Z''(t)} \\ &=& \lim_{t\to t_0} \left(X''(t)^2 + X'(t)\, X'''(t) + Z''(t)^2 + Z'(t)\, Z'''(t)\right) \end{eqnarray}$$

Knowing that $X'(t_0)=Z'(t_0)=0$, you can conclude that $L^2 = X''(t_0)^2  + Z''(t_0)^2$.